# Mongo Changestream getmore profiling

Tags: mongodb, profiler, changestream

While investigating performance issues on our Atlas hosted database, we began to observe a high count of Docs Returned in the Atlas profiler. This high number of returned documents is the result of the changestream `getMore` calls of the cursor, and we sometimes see the number of returned documents reaching over 5000 records. We are aware that we are not making that many changes and are wondering what could explain the high number of records being returned. Is this number a cumulative count from the time the cursor was established?

[image]

Comment: Is the only question here if that number is cumulative or not? It's not. Is there something else that you're trying to learn with this question? If so, please edit the question to clarify what the request is

Comment: Yes, that is the question. However,after doing my own research it appears that this number could be cumulative. I started a watch against my local mongo datatbase and made changes to the collection to see what the result of running db.currentOp({ns:"{dbname}.$cmd"}); would return. The nDocsReturned value seems to be counting up the number of updates made. How do you explain that if not cumulative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> Is the only question here if that number is cumulative or not?
> Yes, that is the question.

No, the number in your screenshot is *not* cumulative.

Your screenshot is from the Atlas profiler. Both [the Atlas profiler documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/tutorial/profile-database/) as well your reference to the screenshot being associated with a `getMore` call point to the fact that we are looking at the results of a single operation.

Somewhat relatedly, the `Response Length` field in that screenshot corresponds to [the `reslen` of the operation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-profiler/#mongodb-data-system.profile.responseLength). Again this is the amount of data transferred for that single call. There is a hard cap of 16MB of data transmitted per batch, so the size of the documents being returned influence how many will get sent in a single batch.

> However,after doing my own research it appears that this number could be cumulative. I started a watch against my local mongo datatbase and made changes to the collection to see what the result of running db.currentOp({ns:"{dbname}.$cmd"}); would return. The nDocsReturned value seems to be counting up the number of updates made. How do you explain that if not cumulative ?

Thanks for the additional context! You are looking at something 'different' here though which is the source of confusion and incorrect conclusion.

In this interface the object being reported against is the *cursor* itself. A [cursor](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) is the object that is created when a query, including a change stream, is executed and will return more than one batch of data.

As you have correctly concluded, the `nDocsReturned` metric in this interface is cumulative for the cursor. [The documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/currentOp/#mongodb-data-currentOp.cursor.nDocsReturned) confirms this:

> The cumulative number of documents returned by the cursor.

[Immediately afterwards](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/currentOp/#mongodb-data-currentOp.cursor.nBatchesReturned) that page also informs us about `nBatchesReturned`:

> **`currentOp.cursor.nBatchesReturned`**
>
> The cumulative number of batches returned by the cursor.

So each *individual `getMore` call* will add to these *cumulative cursor totals* that can be observed in `currentOp`. But the log file and profiler are only going to report the metrics associated with the *individual* `getMore` executions (that are slow enough to be reported in those places).

> We are aware that we are not making that many changes

It sounds like either there are more changes being made than you are expecting or change streams are being (re)opened more often than anticipated (or not using 'resume after' functionality appropriately).

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to explain. I assumed that the "Docs Returned" from the profiler originates from the currentOp.cursor.nBatchesReturned but this seems obviously incorrect.  I thought that the profiler uses the oplogs with `db.currentOp({ns:"{dbname}.$cmd"})` to arrive at the Docs Returned number.

Comment: To provide more context, I am using the MongoDB Kafka connector for an ETL implementation. I don't have control over how the changestream is handled or resumed after an interruption because this is abstracted away by design. The issue with the high document count may be related to the connector's property settings. I need to do a little bit more research. Thank you.

Comment: There are (at least) two different profilers in the MongoDB context, one is built-in to the database and the other is built into the Atlas platform. Neither pull directly from `currentOp` (nor is `currentOp` powered by the oplog, the oplog is a collection that is used for replication purposes). I don't think a high document count is bad - just means there are a lot of changes. Moreover, as you imply, there's really nothing you can do about it. Is there anything about my answer that I can adjust to more completely answer the question you've posed?

Comment: No, I think you have helped me gain a better understanding of the profiler. My issue is that I need the high document count to make sense because the expectation is for the count to correspond with the changes made, and it is not.

Comment: That sounds like a separate interesting issue to dive into, are you going to open a question for it? If so please do share the link here. Troubleshooting that should be relatively straightforward - take a look at the change stream events (or the underlying oplog entries) to find out what changes are taking place and which connection(s) is responsible for them.